# dialogflow WebhookResponse for LINE is not working

Tags: dialogflow-es

LINE <-> DialogFlow <-> My backend server(Generate LINE Msg json)

I got a json from dialogflow webhook as below

```
{'responseId': '...', 'queryResult': {'queryText': 'Test', 'action': 'input.unknown', 'parameters': {}, 'allRequiredParamsPresent': True, 'outputContexts': [{'name': '...', 'lifespanCount': 1, 'parameters': {'no-input': 0, 'no-match': 4}}], 'intent': {'name': '...', 'displayName': 'Default Fallback Intent', 'isFallback': True}, 'intentDetectionConfidence': 1, 'languageCode': 'ko'}, 'originalDetectIntentRequest': {'source': 'line', 'payload': {'data': {'message': {'id': '...', 'type': 'text', 'text': 'Test'}, 'replyToken': 'b485171325dd42fc8de6a2212956e4f1', 'type': 'message', 'source': {'type': 'user', 'userId': '...'}, 'timestamp': '1688022716443'}}}, 'session': '...'}
```

and I generate and send response as below

```
{
  "payload": {
    "line": {
      "type": "flex",
      "altText": "This is a Flex Message",
      "contents": {
        "type": "bubble",
        "body": {
          "type": "box",
          "layout": "horizontal",
          "contents": [
            {
              "type": "text",
              "text": "Hello,"
            },
            {
              "type": "text",
              "text": "World!"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but no msg generated at LINE.

no problem in communications between dialogflow and LINE.